# Matching rows using LIKE column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to match id's between different tables using LIKE instead of using JOINS, this is necessary because of the following scenario

I have 2 tables, the first is called order, the second order_items.

For each order there can be multiple order items so for example typical table values may look something like the following...

```
Table orders

id      sell_price       buy_price
0001    50               20


Table order_items 

id      sell_price       buy_price
0001-1  30               15
0001-2  20               5
```

I have tried creating a query that will be able to return all items for order `0001` using LIKE returning order items `0001-1` and `0001-2`.

```
SELECT 
o.id AS order_id, 
oi.id AS order_item_id,
oi.sell_price AS order_item_sell_price, 
oi.buy_price AS order_item_buy_price  
FROM orders o, order_items oi 
WHERE oi.id LIKE o.id + '%' 
ORDER BY o.purchase_date DESC
```

**No results are returned!**

The problem seems to be with the LIKE statement, I thought this was the correct way to declare it but I guess not, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to move out the ID of the ORDER from the ID of the ORDER_ITEMS into another column ORDER_ID in ORDER_ITEMS. The reason is that you can index ORDER_ID column, which makes your SQL query runs faster.

Comment: I don't understand you exactly, are you saying I should create another column in order_items such as `parent_id` which will be the same ID as the one in the Orders table?

Comment: Yes. The schema of the ORDER_ITEMS table will be id, order_id, sell_price, and buy_price. The row will be 0001-1, 0001, 30, and 15.

Comment: I did this yesterday, should have thought of it earlier, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT 
o.id AS order_id, 
oi.id AS order_item_id,
oi.sell_price AS order_item_sell_price, 
oi.buy_price AS order_item_buy_price  
FROM orders o, order_items oi 
WHERE oi.id LIKE CONCAT(o.id, '%')
ORDER BY o.purchase_date DESC
```

And you can still use a `JOIN` if you want:

```
SELECT 
o.id AS order_id, 
oi.id AS order_item_id,
oi.sell_price AS order_item_sell_price, 
oi.buy_price AS order_item_buy_price  
FROM orders o
JOIN order_items oi on oi.id LIKE CONCAT(o.id, '%')
ORDER BY o.purchase_date DESC
```

A simplified sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6b12/6

Comment: Will do, is it possible to use concat with a join

Comment: @mk_89, your original query is already doing implicit join. There is no difference in both queries mentioned by darkajax

Comment: Yes there should be no problem